# How to not cache an http response with angular httpClient.subcribe()

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, caching

i am using ionic/angular for my app.
In the starting screen (not splashscreen) I get a .json file from my server with

```
this.apiService.getEvents().subscribe res => {
                    console.log(res);
});


getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    return this.httpClient.get("https:www.someURL.com/somejson.json", { headers: headers });
  }
```

but the Observable thingy is caching the whole response. Our file "somejson.json" is manually changed and the ionic app should reload its content at every appstart.

So, how do you NOT cache HTTP GET ?
thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Its cached by browser, not angular. One way to not cache .json get call would be `"https:www.someURL.com/somejson.json?q=" + Date.now()`

Comment: I have added the suggested thing as an answer. Upvote if it does help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use destroy before subscribing to avoid caching.

```
private readonly _destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
this.apiService.getEvents().pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$)).subscribe res => {
                console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The request is not cached by Angular, it is cached by the browser. You can avoid caching by generating unique URL each time

```
getEvents(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    return this.httpClient.get(`https:www.someURL.com/somejson.json?q=${Date.now()}`, { 
      headers: headers
    });
}
```